# Windows - VC++ - Can't "_ASSERTE" be used in static build

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to compile a vc++ code in static mode(using /MT) in visual studio-2008. But I am getting the following error.

```
error Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds
```

I almost tried every options. The errors are due to the macro "_ASSERTE". But, I can't remove those macros as said by my super ordinate. Any help will be awarded with lots of thanks

Answer (score 4):

There error is telling you something real is wrong with your program. While _ASSERTE may be the proximate cause, there is a deeper underlying issue here that you need to address.

Your build scripts or source code are #define-ing _AFXDLL, which is telling MFC that you plan to use the DLL version of MFC. Which requires you to use the DLL version of the CRT as well. But the /MT switch is bringing in the static version of the CRT.

My strongly recommended solution would be to use /MD switch to use the CRT DLL as well as the MFC DLL. You don't explain why you are trying to use /MT, but doing so is very rarely the right choice.

Alternatively, if you are committed to the /MT route, you should not define _AFXDLL.

Finally, there is a small chance you were not intending to use MFC at all. In that case, stop including the MFC headers (afx*.h) and the error will go away.

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own version of `_ASSERTE` which doesn't call `_CrtDbgReportW`, but rather calls your own reporting function.  The issue is the use of `_CrtDbgReportW` within the macro and nothing else.

Comment: Hi, I can't get you. As for as I am concerning any lib can be added either in static way,or in dynamic way. Even, if it calls _CrtDbgReportW, then it should be possible to add that library in static manner. The things I said above are my assumptions and I am new to vc++. Can you explain me how to create my own "_ASSERTE" with the capability of showing some message and terminating the program.

Comment: If you can find the definition of _ASSERTE then simply copy it but call a different function (provided by you) with the same prototype.